# Custom List Adapter Casting Exception

Tags: android

i am making a simple custom listView activity for wich i am setting a custom adapter with custom row style but when i run the application it gives me exception
Here is the code i am trying

**Custom Adapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private ArrayList listData;
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
     Activities Act = new Activities();

     public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

     @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);

                holder.timeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
                holder.refView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ref_tv);
                holder.detailsView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_tv);
                holder.matterView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.titleView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTitle());

            holder.timeView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTime());
            holder.refView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getRef());
            holder.detailsView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getDetails());
           holder.matterView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getMatter());

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView titleView;

            TextView timeView;
            TextView refView;
            TextView detailsView;
            TextView matterView;
        }

}
```

and here is the **Activites** class with getters setters

```
public class Activities implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private String ref;
    private String details;
    private String time;
    private String title;
    private String matter;
    private String date;
    public String getMatter() {
        return matter;
    }
    public void setMatter(String matter) {
        this.matter = matter;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public String getRef() {
        return ref;
    }
    public void setRef(String ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String ref) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

And Here is what the LogCat says

```
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.blavo_timeinn.Activities
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at com.example.blavo_timeinn.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:59)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2084)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1249)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1160)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1374)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:663)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4788)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2105)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12773)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1149)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2583)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-08 12:11:28.784: E/AndroidRuntime(13273):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is how i am **populating** ListView

```
 final ArrayList<String> sData = new ArrayList<String>();
try{

            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("iTimeDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            Cursor c2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Activities", null);  
            if(c2 != null){

            if(c2.moveToFirst()){
                //  c2.moveToFirst();
                do{ 
                SetAct.setTitle(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Title")));
                SetAct.setDetails(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Details")));
                SetAct.setTime(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Time")));
                SetAct.setRef(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Ref")));
                SetAct.setMatter(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Matter")));
                SetAct.setMatter(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Date")));
                sData.add(SetAct.getMatter());
                sData.add(SetAct.getTime());
                sData.add(SetAct.getTitle());
                sData.add(SetAct.getRef());
                sData.add(SetAct.getDetails());


                Log.d("Title",c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Title")));
                Log.d("Details",c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Details")));
                Log.d("Time",SetAct.getTime());
                Log.d("Matter",c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Matter")));
                    } while (c2.moveToNext());
                        }
        }







            c2.close();
            db.close();



            }

            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("YYY", e.toString());
            }
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, sData));
```

Comment: What is this `Activities Act = new Activities();`?? What is the type of `listData`?

Comment: listData is ArrayList

Comment: what is its type a string arraylist??

Comment: can you show how the arraylist is populated

Comment: @ Raghunandan : added in question...

Comment: Now check my post it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.example.blavo_timeinn.Activities
```

Your `listData` is a arraylist of string type.

You need to check how you populate the list

You have this

```
 final ArrayList<String> sData = new ArrayList<String>()
```

This is what is passed to the constructor

So what you are doing is wrong casting string to Activities

To correct

```
 final ArrayList<Activities> sData = new ArrayList<Activities>();
```

Then

```
 for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
  Activites act = new Activities();
  String title =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Title")));
  String details =(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Details")));
  String time =c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Time")));
  String ref= c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Ref")));
  String matter =(c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Matter")));
  String date = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("Date")));
  act.setTitle(title);
  ...//  similarly for others
  sData.add(act); 
 }
```

Now pass sData to the constructor of adapter class

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, sData));
```

Then

```
private ArrayList<Activities> listData;
public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Activities> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

Then in `getView`

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);

            holder.timeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
            holder.refView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ref_tv);
            holder.detailsView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_tv);
            holder.matterView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Activities act = listData.get(position)
        holder.titleView.setText(act.getTitle());

        holder.timeView.setText(act.getTime());
        holder.refView.setText(act.getRef());
        holder.detailsView.setText(act.getDetails());
        holder.matterView.setText(act.getMatter());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: @AdilWaqar glad to help. I have not shown the setter for all data. SO make sure you do that @ `...//  similarly` for others in my post

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because of the below code where you have tried to cast your `ArrayList` into the `Activity`

```
    holder.titleView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTitle());
        holder.timeView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTime());
        holder.refView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getRef());
        holder.detailsView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getDetails());
       holder.matterView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getMatter());
```

Change your **private ArrayList listData;** to **private ArrayList listData;**
as its should contains the data of the `Activities` which you have added into.

```
private ArrayList<Activities> listData;
 public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Activities> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }
```

Comment: yeah i know first i tried without casting like this   holder.matterView.setText(listData.get(position).getMatter()); but i gave me syntax error

Comment: The method getMatter() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: Change your `private ArrayList listData;` to `private ArrayList<Activities>  listData;`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify in your array list about the kind of data it is going to hold. In you case it's activities. So that you wont have to type cast when you get items.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private ArrayList<Activities> listData;
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
     Activities Act = new Activities();

     public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Activities> listData) {
            this.listData = listData;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

     @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);

                holder.timeView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time_tv);
                holder.refView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ref_tv);
                holder.detailsView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.detail_tv);
                holder.matterView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.titleView.setText(listData.get(position).getTitle());

            holder.timeView.setText(listData.get(position).getTime());
            holder.refView.setText(listData.get(position).getRef());
            holder.detailsView.setText(listData.get(position).getDetails());
           holder.matterView.setText(listData.get(position).getMatter());

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView titleView;

            TextView timeView;
            TextView refView;
            TextView detailsView;
            TextView matterView;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason you got the exception you are trying to cas `ArrayList` to `Activity`. Change `private ArrayList listData;` to `private ArrayList<Activities > listData;`

```
holder.titleView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTitle()); 
holder.timeView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getTime());
holder.refView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getRef());
holder.detailsView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getDetails());
holder.matterView.setText(((Activities) listData.get(position)).getMatter());
```

Try like this

```
holder.titleView.setText(listData.get(position)).getTitle());
```